# Objective-C Zlib method with potential leak

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, byte, zlib

I have just analyzed my code and found a analysis error.

```
Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'decompressedBytes'
```

I have never had such an error, I have done some hunting around but cannot figure out how to fix this "potential leak".

This is what my code looks like

```
- (NSData*) dataByDecompressingData:(NSData*)data{
    Byte* bytes = (Byte*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger len = [data length];
    NSMutableData *decompressedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:COMPRESSION_BLOCK];
    Byte* decompressedBytes = (Byte*) malloc(COMPRESSION_BLOCK);
    
    z_stream stream;
    int err;
    stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
    stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;
    
    stream.next_in = bytes;
    err = inflateInit(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateInit");
    
    while (true) {
        stream.avail_in = len - stream.total_in;
        stream.next_out = decompressedBytes;
        stream.avail_out = COMPRESSION_BLOCK;
        err = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        [decompressedData appendBytes:decompressedBytes length:(stream.total_out-[decompressedData length])];
        if(err == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;
        CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflate");
    }
    
    err = inflateEnd(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateEnd");
    
    free(decompressedBytes);
    return decompressedData;
}
```

Comment: @Kevin it is `malloc`ed memory, nothing to do with ARC. @HurkNburkS What is CHECK_ERR? does it do early return?

Comment: you dont have autorelease for decompressedData

Comment: Xcode will give you the path it calculates that can leak. What does it show?

Comment: Check CHECK_ERR for `return`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was trying to figure out what was going on for myself. HOwever @Bryan's anwer did work. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your `CHECK_ERR` happen to be something like `if (err) return nil` then the warning means your function have early return and may not always free memory you `malloc`ed

you should avoid `malloc` if possible.

try this

```
NSMutableData *decompressedBytesData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:COMPRESSION_BLOCK]; // autorelease if not ARC
Byte* decompressedBytes = (Byte*)[decompressedBytesData mutableBytes];

// you don't need free(decompressedBytes);
```

Comment: Yes this worked thankyou. Sorry for the late reply I was debugging trying to figure out where the problem was for myself :P